# In Unity, how do you check if a camera is rendering anything? (Unity 2018.3)

Tags: unity

I'm trying to have a camera automatically disable if it's not rendering anything.

Is there a simple way to check if a camera is blank/empty?

Edit: Alternatively, is there a way to prevent a camera from rendering if there is nothing in it's view?

- For example, I do not want MSAA applied to a blank camera. (I'd hope it would attempt AA, but effectively do zero work)

Comment: What's the structure of your scene, that results in cameras unpredictably having nothing to render? A render of nothing should be very cheap — just a frustum culling pass, the same work you'd need to do to determine it's empty anyway — so are you sure this is the bottleneck in your game?

Comment: I'm testing on a low-end android, and the blank cameras are taking 2ms or so each to render. The cameras are used for temporary UIs and overlays.

In case it matters, the sometimes-blank cameras have their Clear Flags set to "Depth only"

Comment: Then it seems like your UI state management logic should be able to handle turning them on & off, no?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but it wasn't going to be super easy to track when the overlays were finished (since external conditions determine how long they're needed). So, I thought I could just have the cameras themselves poll for being blank and disable themselves.

Comment: You want to design this the other way around. Your UI manager could have a set of callbacks, such as OnWindowOpen/Closed or OnAllWindowsOpened/Closed that interested objects could listen to. So in your case, a UI camera render optimisation object could register for these callbacks and turn the relevant cameras on/off as the callbacks trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mt_. I was going to do something like this if I couldn't find a way to do an "are you blank?" check on the camera. It would be silly to me if there wasn't some way to determine if the camera was blank. I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I think if you're concerned about performance, fixing this problem at its source will be the most efficient option. Want to try reframing your question as "How can I eliminate unnecessary rendering when changing UI states"? That way options to automatically disable cameras are still a valid answer, but so are state management strategies that will let you choreograph when to turn them on/off.

Comment: Interesting idea – I'll edit my question. Only one extra camera is for UI, another is for special effects. (This doesn't really change anything, besides needing an additional management system) I'd like to avoid making systems to keep track of visibility because it feels like a many-to-one (many objects/UI elements/etc. to one camera) relationship. I of course already manage states to some extent, but tying visibility to them isn't as elegant as I'd like due to animations and randomness in them.